# Assign xib to the UIView in Swift

Tags: uiview, swift, xib

in objective c it can be done in init method by

```
-(id)init{
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewBtnWishList" owner:0 options:nil]     objectAtIndex:0];
return self;
}
```

but when i do this in swift

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    self = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewDetailMenu", owner: 0, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
}
```

cannot assign to self in a method error is shown.
now my approach is to create a view, and add the view loaded from nib to it.
anyone have a better idea?

Comment: using `UINib` would be much more efficient... anyway, the `self` cannot be assigned in _Swift_. you may want to create a class method which inits your class using a _xib_ file.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

**for Swift 4**

```
extension UIView {
    class func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle: Bundle? = nil) -> UIView? {
      return UINib(
          nibName: nibNamed,
          bundle: bundle
      ).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
  }
}
```

**for Swift 3**

You could create an extension on UIView:

```
extension UIView {
    class func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle: NSBundle? = nil) -> UIView? {
        return UINib(
            nibName: nibNamed,
            bundle: bundle
        ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    }
}
```

**Note**: Using UINib is faster because it does caching for you.

Then you can just do:

```
ViewDetailItem.loadFromNibNamed("ViewBtnWishList")
```

And you will be able to reuse that method on any view.

Comment: why are you using the 3-4 times _slower_ `NSBundle` to load a nib?

Comment: @holex I was just trying to keep that code consistent to address the actual question, but I updated it.

Comment: for me it is fine, I'm just asking. anyway, the `bundle` should be `nil` in that case if you are not using specific bundle but the default one. :)

Comment: @holex, I believe there is an issue in the beta right now where using nil for the bundle does not work

Comment: I have not experienced such thing, I pass `nil` as bundle, and the nib is loaded properly; my code, I've posted as answer, is fully functioning.

Comment: At this juncture, using NSStringFromClass may be problematic if you don't also use @objc to assign a specific Objective-C class name, since the mangled name will be returned otherwise.

Comment: thanks,so i can create the custom uiview as follow??
var customView = ViewDetailItem.loadFromNibNamed("ViewBtnWishList")

but what if I want to initialize some more variable when the custom view created? In this case, did we just bypass the init methods of UIView?

Comment: Don't forget the "import UIKit" line on top of the document

Comment: @drewag: Am I doing something wrong? [I'm trying to use](http://pastebin.com/2DCUztSk) and [my extension class](http://pastebin.com/gTakqrau)

Comment: @el.severo and what problem are you having?

Comment: @drewag: I couldn't instantiate / load a view (.xib) file. It threw me a crash error. I ended up using different approach. I was trying to load some xib to iCarousel object

Comment: @el.severo at brief inspection of the code I don't see a problem. Make sure the nib is named correctly and that it is actually being compiled into the binary

Comment: I have a problem if i use this in a layout which contains other View, and then i make outlet to the class, I'm getting `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x17000bae0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key infoView.'`

Comment: Is it possible to load the nib file inside the UIView itself?

Comment: Just curious - Why use the class func instead of static func

Comment: @beretis Check if you accidentally pin your infoView to File's Owner. You should rather pin it to the View.

Comment: Really nice. Though I had more use of the function in a generic form:  ```  class func loadFromNibNamed<T: UIView>(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> T? {
        return UINib(
            nibName: nibNamed,
            bundle: bundle
            ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? T
    }```

Comment: Can you anyone tell me what is ViewDetailItem here? and In which file the extension method should be declared?

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me.

```
override func awakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder) -> AnyObject? {
    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        return loadNib()
    }
    return self
}

private func loadNib() -> YourCustomView {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourCustomViewNibName", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as YourCustomView
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution for reuse within a storyboard or xib file. If you simply add the loaded nib view as a subview, properties like delegates don't get set properly

Comment: Make sure if you have any outlets, that you connect them to the View in your XIB, not `File Owner`, or else you'll get KVO-compliance errors.

Comment: This is so far the only one that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: The most appropriate solution in any way. I don't know why only 10 up votes here before I found it.

Comment: But unfortunately, when working with storyboard, this solution replace the object originally in the storyboard indeed, which leading a situation where your view constraints or any other setup done by storyboard gone disappear.

Answer (score 24):

Tested in Xcode 7 beta 4 , Swift 2.0 . 
The following code will assign xib to the `UIView`.
You can use this custom xib view in storyboard and access the `IBOutlet` object also.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class SimpleCustomView:UIView
{
    var view:UIView!;

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

   @IBInspectable var lblTitleText : String?
        {
        get{
            return lblTitle.text;
        }
        set(lblTitleText)
        {
            lblTitle.text = lblTitleText!;
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib ()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib ()
    }
    func loadViewFromNib() {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SimpleCustomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(view);



    }


}
```

Access customview programatically

```
self.customView =  SimpleCustomView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200))
        self.view.addSubview(self.customView!);
```

Source code - https://github.com/karthikprabhuA/CustomXIBSwift

Comment: Works in other XIBs as well - that's great. However - one problem, this isn't creating a custom view directly from a XIB. It is loading a UIView from a XIB and adding it as a subview to the custom view.

Comment: A most exellent contribution. Very clear and complete. THANKS for posting it with the Github repo too!

One small issue the member variable "view" inside `SimpleCustomView.swift` appears to be unecessary and unused.

Comment: one from a lot of solutions which isn't setup view from a static method)

Answer (score 18):

that may be a solution for you:

#### Swift 3.x

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "<<NibFileName>>", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
```

---

#### Swift 2.x

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "<<NibFileName>>", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as UIView
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Short, concise and works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: So would I put this code in the XIB's view controller or the view controller I'm trying to add the XIB to?

Comment: @MarksCode, you need to add this snippet to the subset of the `UIView` class; that is nothing to do with any view-conrollers in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easies but also the cleanest way to assign a xib to a UIView. Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.0.

```
import UIKit

//Create CustomView class
class CustomView: UIView {

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
}

//Use it
let customView = CustomView.instanceFromNib() as! CustomView
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The true **Swift** approach is the use of protocols and protocol extensions.

> I use it like this: To start I create a protocol

```
    protocol XibInitializable {
        static var name: String { get }
        static var bundle: Bundle? { get }

        static func fromXib() -> Self
    }
```

> then I make a default implementation of this protocol use protocol extention

```
extension XibInitializable where Self : UIView {
    static var name: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    static var bundle: Bundle? {
        return nil
    }

    static func fromXib() -> Self {
        return UINib(nibName: name, bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! Self
    }
}
```

the implementation of our protocol is now complete

***In order for this protocol to work, you need the name of our xib file and the class were the same. For example, for example***

[image]

finally add the protocol and make your class "**final**", like here.

[image]

**That's it**

> and use

[image]

Comment: The only thing I'd change is to move the `bundle` property into the function as a parameter that defaults to `nil`. I'd also use `nibName` instead of `name`

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding an extension to UIView, you could define a protocol and add the implementation to a protocol extension. You can then declare that UIView conforms to the protocol.

This allows the return type to be `Self` instead of `UIView`. So the caller doesn't have to cast to the class.

Explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424509/845027

```
import UIKit

protocol UIViewLoading {}
extension UIView : UIViewLoading {}

extension UIViewLoading where Self : UIView {

  // note that this method returns an instance of type `Self`, rather than UIView
  static func loadFromNib() -> Self {
    let nibName = "\(self)".characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init).last!
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! Self
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made a `UINib` extension to load a view from xib and embed into a container view using constraints, using generics and strong naming (without using Strings, assuming you have the same file name for xib and implementation):

```
extension UINib {

    static func instantiateViewAndEmbedWithConstraints <T: UIView> (viewType viewType: T.Type, embedInto containerView: UIView) -> T {
        let view = UINib(nibName: String(viewType), bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil).first as! T
        containerView.addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        return view
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
...outlets...
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
var customView: CustomView!

...viewDidLoad...
customView = UINib.instantiateViewAndEmbedWithConstraints(viewType: CustomView.self, embedInto: containerView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass this simple class (swift 5):

```
open class NibView: UIView {

    open override func awakeAfter(using coder: NSCoder) -> Any? {
        if subviews.count == 0 {
            return UINib(nibName: "\(Self.self)", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        }
        return self
    }
}

class CustomView: NibView {
}
```

As others pointed out, set File's Owner to your `CustomView` class (not xib's root view itself). Then set custom class to `CustomView` to any view that you want to be replaced by your custom view class. Also, autolayout respects all constraints inside your xib, at least as a subview of a UITableViewCell's content view. Not sure about other cases.

As simple, as it happens to be, somehow Apple did another quest for us for such a basic thing! What a wonderful company! Never gonna be bored with them!