# Blank/Black view when attempting to set delegate/data source

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I am attempting to load a view from a .xib file as per this question:
[Assign xib to the UIView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370061/assign-xib-to-the-uiview-in-swift)

My setup is as follows:

- **StripView.xib** — the .xib file from which I am loading the view, contains a single UIView
- **StripView.swift** — the 'owner' of the UIView in StripView.xib, contains references/IBOutlets for each component in StripView.xib
- **StripViewController.swift** — The view controller, which loads an instance of StripView and handles most of the logic/data source/delegate stuff.

This all worked fine in Xcode 6 Beta 4, however, upgrading to Xcode 6 Beta 5 (the latest) breaks. On app launch, I simply get a blank, black screen. All other parts of the app seem to work fine. This bug only occurs when I attempt to set the delegate or data source of a UIPickerView (owned by StripView) to the StripViewController.

Code snippet:

```
class StripViewController: SWRevealViewController, RSColorPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, BLEDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
var stripView: StripView!
var colorPicker: RSColorPickerView!
var connectBtn:UIButton!
var connectionSpinner:UIActivityIndicatorView!

var tapRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer!

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // use UIView extension as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370061/assign-xib-to-the-uiview-in-swift
    stripView = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("StripView") as StripView
    self.view.addSubview(stripView)

    // nav bar setup //
    self.title = "Strip \(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex+1)"

    let leftNav:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,40))

    self.connectBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,95,40))
    connectBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,connectBtn.bounds.size.width,connectBtn.bounds.size.height)
    connectBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
    connectBtn.setTitle("Connect", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    connectBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    connectBtn.addTarget(self, action: "connectButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    leftNav.addSubview(connectBtn)

    self.connectionSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
    connectionSpinner.frame = CGRectMake(connectBtn.frame.minX + connectBtn.bounds.size.width, connectBtn.frame.minY + 10, connectionSpinner.bounds.size.width, connectionSpinner.bounds.size.height)
    connectionSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    leftNav.addSubview(connectionSpinner)

    let leftNavItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftNav)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavItem

    // set up color picker
    colorPicker = RSColorPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 78, 160, 160))
    self.view.addSubview(colorPicker)
    colorPicker.delegate = self

    // set up mode picker
    // THESE APPEAR TO BE THE OFFENDING LINES —
    // COMMENTING THEM OUT DISPLAYS THE VIEW AS EXPECTED
    self.stripView.modePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.stripView.modePicker.delegate = self;

    // set up notifications
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "colorFieldDidChange:", name: "ColorFieldDidChangeNotification", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    // set up UI and populate fields
    self.stripView.setAnimSpeed()

    // set up BLE
    BLEManager.instance.ble.delegate = self
}

[...]
```

Once more, the offending lines appear to be:

```
self.stripView.modePicker.dataSource = self;
self.stripView.modePicker.delegate = self;
```

If I comment them out, all else displays as normal. I even attempted moving the delegate/data source into StripView.swift (not StripViewController), but I see the same result.

Here's the part of StripViewController that implements UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate methods:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int     {
    return DataModel.instance.ModeNames.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return DataModel.instance.ModeNames[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // send mode to arduino
    println("--- sending mode select command ---")
    var buf:[UInt8] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
    buf[0] = Modes.instance.SET_MODE
    buf[1] = UInt8(DataModel.instance.ModeOpcodes[DataModel.instance.ModeNames[row]]!)

    let data:NSData = NSData(bytes: buf, length: 4)
    BLEManager.instance.ble.write(data)
}
```

Did something change in the way the Swift language handles delegates/data sources, or view loading from a XIB?

---

EDIT:
I've narrowed down the problem to the DataModel singleton I'm using as a datasource. That code (DataModel.swift) looks like so, implementing a basic singleton pattern as per https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton :

```
class DataModel {
// setup singleton
    class var instance: DataModel {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : DataModel = DataModel()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    // modes
    // eventually may replace this with a more flexible data structure
    // for now, we just need names
    let ModeNames: Array<String> = ["Light All", "Rainbow"]

    let ModeOpcodes: Dictionary<String, UInt8> = [DataModel.instance.ModeNames[0]: Modes.instance.LIGHT_ALL, DataModel.instance.ModeNames[1]: Modes.instance.RAINBOW];
}
```

Replacing instances of this with a variable defined in StripViewController results in things working fine. Something about it being a singleton seems to be throwing things off. Thoughts? Perhaps the singleton is not being instantiated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

One thing easily overlooked is connecting the data source and delegate to the view controller itself. In addition to ctrl dragging an outlet, you need to ctrl drag the data source and delegate from the connections inspector to the small view controller icon on top of the view in the storyboard.