# Swift: Creating a button that calls a method in another class1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, segue

I have 2 classes, the first class is named "store" where I create a button which calls a method: *"storeSelected"* located in the second class with the name `ExploreViewController`. 
The method should print "done" and take me to another view controller.
Without the segue "done" is printed but when putting the segue code the app crashes.

The error is: 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Glam.ExploreViewController: 0x14ed3be20>) has no segue with identifier 'ok''`
.........

```
// ExploreViewController Class

let _sharedMonitor: ExploreViewController = { ExploreViewController() }()

class ExploreViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    class func sharedMonitor() -> ExploreViewController {
        return _sharedMonitor
    }


    func storeSelected(sender: UIButton) {                        
        println("done") // it entered here and "done" is printed                                                                   
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ok", sender: self) //here is the problem                           
    }
}







// another class named "Store"  
// button is created

let monitor = ExploreViewController.sharedMonitor()
btn.addTarget(monitor, action: Selector("storeSelected:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Do you definitely have a manual segue with the identifier "ok" linked to your `ExploreViewController` ?

Comment: Yes I have, and it works fine when I put the segue in viewdidload for example. @Wezly

Comment: And is there a specific reason for having the button event handled in the `ExploreViewController` ? - I would just do it from the `Store` and add a second manual segue from the `Store` to wherever it is you want to go.

Comment: Store class is a class of type UIView, can I put segue code in it? @Wezly

Comment: Ah - I did not know that. you should handle the segue in the currently visible View Controller, I assume your `Store` object is inside one somewhere?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming that you have a view controller where you create the `Store` object - you should pass the button action back to this view controller and add a segue from it to your desired destination.

**Best practice is to use a protocol that delegates the buttons action back up to the viewController that it is contained in as below.**

### Store.swift

```
protocol StoreDelegate: NSObject {
    func didPressButton(button: UIButton)
}

class Store: UIView {

    weak var delegate: StoreDelegate!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        var button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle(
            "button", 
            forState: .Normal
        )
        button.addTarget(
            self, 
            action: "buttonPress:", 
            forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside
        )
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonPress(button: UIButton) {
        delegate.didPressButton(button)
    }

}
```

### ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, StoreDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addStoreObj()
    }

    func addStoreObj() {
        var store = Store()
        store.delegate = self // IMPORTANT
        self.view.addSubview(store)
    }

    func didPressButton(button: UIButton) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(
            "ok", 
            sender: nil
        )
    }

}
```

This code is untested, but I hope you get the idea - your `Store` object delegates the button press activity back to its containing `ViewController` and then the ViewController carries out the segue that you have attached to it in the Storyboard.

Comment: This is great example of delegate design pattern but I'm just wondering whether this is the only (though I can see it's best practice) way to perform this? I was thinking about passing the ViewController by reference, but I can see it's bad.

Comment: Another way might be to pass a closure from the main view controller to the store view but you still need to action the segue from the view controller, therefore, probably still needing to pass a reference.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!, people dont forget: store.delegate = self

Comment: What can be the reason that 'buttonPress' method not called?

Comment: Also dont forget to do this in your code:  protocol StoreDelegate : class { ...} also define weak var delegate:StoreDelegate? to avoid memory leaks

Comment: That's true, make sure to use weak var on delegate otherwise you will have a strong reference between view and controller.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the delegate var to have a weak reference.