# Button Action from UITableViewCell to ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates

I am trying to implement the Delegate way to do some action on a button tap from my UITableViewCell to a ViewController. The following is what I have so far -

**TableViewCell:**

```
protocol UserCellDelegate : class {
    func disableUser(cell: UserCell, button: UIButton)
}

class UserCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userDescription: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var writeOutUser: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: UserCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        writeOutUser.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }


    @IBAction func disableUserButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.disableUser(self, button: writeOutUser)  //self here I believe to be the cell 
    }


}
```

**ViewController:**

```
class UserDetailTableViewController : UIViewController, UserCellDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let userCell = UserCell()
      userCell.delegate = self
    }

    func disableUser(cell: UserCell, button: UIButton) {
      print("VC: User Disabled")
    }
}
```

The problem here is, the disableUser function in my ViewController never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

What is the best way to do it?

I had referred to the [SO Approved Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602612/swift-creating-a-button-that-calls-a-method-in-another-class1) which is what I am following the same, but with no luck.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: looks like your delegate is nil in vieDidLoad. YOu should set the delagate in the cellForRow method

Comment: You cannot initialize an instance of `UITableViewCell` with the default initializer `()`. You have to call the designated initializer `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`. In Swift it's more convenient to use a callback closure rather than the delegate pattern.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri: That did the trick! I overlooked the fact that it's a tableViewCell :-(

Comment: i am not find Code like this
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
where are you implement UITableViewDataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `delegate` of your cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.As @vadian said,In the viewDidLoad you should not initialize your cell using default initializer, and the delegate is nil for your cell by this way in `viewDidLoad`.

Either initialise your cell using the init(style: reuseIdentifier) or set the delegate in the cell for row method as you will initialize the cell in that method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing this:

```
let userCell = UserCell()
userCell.delegate = self
```

You are setting the delegate of `userCell`, and *only* the delegate of `userCell`. I'm sure that the table view cells displayed in your table view is *not* `userCell`.

So instead of setting the delegate of `userCell`, you should set the delegate of the cells that you actually want to show in the table view. The most probable place to create new cells that you want to show in table view is in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

In the method, you must have something like this:

```
let cell = ...
// setting properties of cell using the model
return cell
```

You just need to add this line before the return:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `UserCell` acts like a `UIView`. You forgot adding `userCell` to current controller's view. If you want to use `UITableViewCell`, the better way is using it with UITableView.