# programmatically customize UIView in xib

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I've created a Xib file with a UIView and then created a custom UIView class connected to the xibs file owner. However i'm not sure how to create something programatically. I've tried to add the awakeFromNib function however it seems not ro run, what method should implement in order to change backgroundColor programmatically?

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MediaPlayer", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
```

Comment: How are the views being initialized when you use them? Are they being initialized using the .xib or are they using an init() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` will be called only if call `UINib` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513605/846780

Comment: are you sure that `let view` is not nil?

Comment: not really however it shows my xib file in the view, so i guess it is not?

Comment: So you need to investigate.. What you did should call `override func awakeFromNib()` method. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib

Answer (score 0):

You can change backgroundColor of any like this.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your custom view .xib file
2. Create a .swift file subclass of UIView
3. Set file's owner to your subclass

[Set files owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmc9o.png)

4. Drag the file's view into .swift file and call it contentView

[Connect IBOutlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZUrw.png)

Your UIView subclass should look like this:

```
class CustomView : UIView {


  @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!



  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setup()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  func setup() {
    Bundle(for: CustomView.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: CustomView.self), owner: self, options: nil)
  }
}
```

6. Now you can use your subclass directly in Interface Builder

[Custom view in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2elyW.png)

7. Or programatically

[Custom view programatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c6H7.png)

```
let view = CustomView()
```