# Connecting an .xib-File to a Custom Class

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uiview, xib

I have created a custom .xib-file and a custom subclass of `UIView`. 
**What is the procedure to connect the two?**

Meaning that when I set `MyCustomClass` in the custom class attribute, it turns into my custom .xib-file and acts according to MyCustomClass.swift.

Comment: just add the class name (StoryBoard inspector) in XIB as your UIView subclass name.

Comment: you can follow this link ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i

Answer (score 2):

Click on your Xib file and go here and set your custom Class here

[image: Set your custom class name here]

Comment: While googling I have found many tutorials that say you need to add code to MyCustomClass.swift in order to load from the .xib.
Are they all outdated?

Comment: Dude, I don't know about link what you mentioned.

Comment: Excuse me. For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513271/how-to-initialise-a-uiview-class-with-a-xib-file-in-swift-ios or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i

Comment: you need to write this in your class. because so far what you did my way is to added the class file with the nib file.But how will you access it from another View contoller? Thats the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

**Select** `Whatever.xib` >> **Click** `Show Identity Inspector` >> **Focus at** `Custom Class` >> **Edit** `Class` as `MyCustomClass` 
See this example for Test.xib and Test.swift : 
[image][image]