# Google maps api for ios not showing custom info window properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to add a map in my app that shows dome locations and a description of each location in a custom info window which is supposed to look like that:

[image]

So i have made an xib file with a class to make the custom window which looks like that:

[image]

And its class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomInfoWindow: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet weak var desc = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    init(name:String, desc:String) {
        self.name?.text = name
        self.desc?.text = desc
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Now whenever I implement the map's delegate method that returns a UIView for the marker info window and add the text as in here:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    if marker.position.latitude == latitude && marker.position.longitude == longitude{
        marker.title = "You"
        return nil
    }else{
    let customWindow = CustomInfoWindow(name: theName!, desc: theDesc!)
    return customWindow.view

    }
}
```

That is what I get:

[image]

This problem has been annoying me for so much time, so how can I fix it??

Comment: you forgot one thing that you did not give any frame of your xib file so its look like that you need to give frame of your .xib file

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: in your xib file create like your main view set its view  color clear color and put your popup view in center of your xib file and check it output.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  i dont actually understand what you are trying to say, what is border color and what popup view in center

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051928/6656894 check this

Comment: It gives me this runtime error when i do this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'nib file name'

Comment: your bundle name and your xib name not same please check that name from storyboard that your give class name

Comment: Why is the nib file not accepting any custom class when i try to write one

Comment: Must the bundle name be the same as the xib file??

Comment: in file owner name you have to give it same one of your class name

Comment: Yeah okay i checked that and the class name was there

Comment: Sorry i haven't worked with xib before, please i need your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146388/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-user3407319).