# Why is my popup view is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xib

I am trying to make a popup view similar to [this one](https://github.com/psy2k/NMPopUpView). What I have done so far is:

- Open a new single view project.
- Added a button to the main view.
- Added a new xib file named "popup.xib"
- Added a new swift file named "PopupViewController.swift"
- At the identity tab I made the first responders class to be "PopupViewController"
- I put in the popup.xib a label, a button and a view with different background colour. Of course everything has constraints about where it should appear.

My code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showPopup(sender: AnyObject) {
        var x = PopupViewController()
        x.show(self.view)
        x.showAnimate()
    }
}
```

PopupViewController

```
import UIKit

class PopupViewController : UIViewController {

    func show(tView : UIView) {
        tView.addSubview(self.view)
        println("here")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }

    func showAnimate() {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        self.view.alpha = 0.3
    }

}
```

The result: When the button is pressed I get a redish overlay on the view (because the view I added is red and has 30% opacity), but the new view is empty. No button, no label, no area with different colour.

What do I have to do to make the popup.xib show it's elements?

---

## Update

I was missing the connection between the File's Owner and the main view in addition to `Nerkyator`s answer. Just right click the "File's Onwer" and from view drag to the main view that is two lines below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load manually the xib associated to your view.
I use this extensions ([found at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370061/assign-xib-to-the-uiview-in-swift)) modified to support UIViewController and then I call it when needed.

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> Self? {
        return UINib(
            nibName: nibNamed,
            bundle: bundle
            ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIViewController
    }
}
```

then

```
@IBAction func showPopup(sender: AnyObject) {
    var x = PopupViewController.loadFromNibNamed("popup")
    //do what you need with x
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason I get `'PopupViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'loadControllerFromNibNamed'`. Tried to put it in both files and in a separate file. Nothing worked. (I tried to make clean an build again)

Comment: I edited my previous reply, there was a typo on it.  Now it is correct (no more "Controller" in `loadFromNibNamed`).

Comment: Now it compiles, but for some reason x is nil, and I get an error when I access it.

Comment: The "popup" which is sent as an argument to `loadFromNibNamed`, should be the file name, right?

Comment: exactly, you have to use the xib filename

Comment: I do (even copy-pasted the name). It returns me nil. :-\

Comment: Try to load it manually without extensions:

var x = PopupViewController(nibName: "popup", bundle: nil)

[manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle)

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear that!

Comment: There is a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278345/does-not-have-a-member-instantiatewithowner), if you are interested.

Comment: By using `Self?` as the return type, you can avoid casting the result.