# does not have a member 'instantiateWithOwner'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to make a popup like I described in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275302/why-is-my-popup-view-is-empty). I actually got an answer, but now I have a new problem. I can make the view appear if I don't make the `instantiateWithOwner`, but it is not responding to anything (just frozen).

In short, I have set up a 'popup.xib' file, which is just a view with a button and a label. My code below should make it appear and disappear with button clicks.

I have read the documentation that the `instantiateWithOwner` does all the magic of connecting the view to it's callback buttons, so it makes sense that nothing happens when it's not in the code. ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UINib/nibWithNibName:bundle:))

Thing is that if I do include it in my code, I get a compiler error `'PopupViewConrtoller' does not have a member named 'instantiateWithOwner'`.

I have tried searching the auto-complete list, but found nothing similar.

My code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showPopup(sender: AnyObject) {
         // This line makes it appear on the screen, but not respond to anything.
        var x = PickerPopupViewConrtoller(nibName: "PickerPopup", bundle: nil)
         // This line does not compile.
        var x = PickerPopupViewConrtoller(nibName: "PickerPopup", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? PickerPopupViewConrtoller

        x.show(self.view)
    }
}
```

PopupViewController

```
import UIKit

class PickerPopupViewConrtoller : UIViewController {

    func show(tView : UIView) {
        tView.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct, `instantiateWithOwner` is not a UIViewController method, it is a [UINib](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINib/instantiateWithOwner:options:) method.
You have to create a UINib object and then cast it to your UIViewController class

ex:

```
UINib( nibName: nibNamed, bundle: bundle).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIViewController
```

That's why I use the extension I wrote in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275627/2475007), it's easier and more readable.

Comment: Don't worry, I think those are common errors when starting using a new language or a new IDE ;)

Comment: Another [followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279401/when-i-try-to-instantiate-a-uinib-i-get-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-comp)

Answer (score 0):

`instantiateWithOwner` is a method on `UINib`. You are calling it on a `UIViewController` instance.

The correct code would be along the following lines:

```
UINib(nibName: 'PickerPopup', bundle: UIBundle.mainBundle().instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? PickerPopupViewController
```

The `instantiateWithOwner` method will actually call the `PickerPopupViewController` constructor (`PickerPopupViewController.init(coder:)`)