# When I try to instantiate a UINib I get: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

Followup on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278345/does-not-have-a-member-instantiatewithowner).

I have an app, where the main view has one button, and a file 'popup.xib' which is now empty (Just a view, no buttons, no labels, nothing). And I want it to popup when I press the button. For some reason I get the following error whenever I press the button:

> ... this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

I have read that this is because of outlets from the NIB which have been deleted or changed, that's why I removed all objects and what to display an empty view. But I still get this error.

My code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showPopup(sender: AnyObject) {
        var x = UINib(nibName: "Popup", bundle: nil);
        println(x)
        var y = x.instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)

        println(y)

        var z = y[0] as? PopupViewController

        println(z)
        z!.show(self.view)
    }


}
```

PopupViewController.swift

```
import UIKit


class PopupViewController : UIViewController {

    func show(tView : UIView) {
        tView.addSubview(self.view)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

}
```

The output:

```
<UINib: 0x7ff822412f90>
2015-02-02 15:47:57.870 tttt[5437:179808] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7ff822553ec0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

---

## Update

[image]

---

## Update 2

I continued tweaking stuff according to the answers and comments, and got if I do `var y = x.instantiateWithOwner(PopupViewController(), options: nil)` the line get executed OK. But then I get back an array containing a UIView, not a UIViewController. Therefore the last line `z!.show(self.view)` causes a crash. I know it creates the right nib, cause the properties (e.g. alpha value) that I changed appear in the text output from `println(y)` correctly.

So my question now is: What should I pass as the owner into `instantiateWithOwner`?

Comment: Did you try to use self as owner parameter.

Comment: Tried now, variable z is still nil.

Comment: Actually y is still a list of one `UIView`, so the cast does not work and nil is used.

Comment: rename the .xib to PopupViewController.xib, and call var x = UINib(nibName: "PopupViewController", bundle: nil); and delete the instantiateWithOwner part.

Comment: it's strange your problem. are your viewcontroller and .xib included in the target that you run with?

Comment: I know it's strange. I probably missed the most obvious thing. But I just checked. They are marked

Comment: Try to use:  var nibs = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NibNameHere", owner: self, options: nil);   Then if nibs is not nil (it find your nib), get the first in that array.

Comment: @tyt_g207 Thanks for the idea, unfortunately, this also gives me an array containing a UIView, not a UIViewController. :-\

Comment: @tyt_g207 I Made it work thanks to you. It needed some weird tweaks but now have a working example.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice to see it works. So, what are the tweaks?

Comment: At the end I didn't use `loadNibNamed` but the regular option presented at `Nerkyator`s answer. But replaced the owner instead of nil it is an instance of whatever class I want, and then use `presentViewController` to show it. I have no idea why this works. You solution made it show, but never responded properly. Anyway I have a working example. So many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check what kind of class you have as the file owner.  The error seems to be saying that it's trying to link the view in your .xib to a plain `NSObject` which, of course, has no view property.

If you don't want an owner that links to the view, make sure that there are no view outlets.  Also verify that the file's owner is a type of object that really exists.

Comment: Done that. See my update. What do you mean "object that really exists"? I have checked that there is no typo if that's what you mean.

Comment: Using your image as an example, I mean being sure that there really is a `PopupViewController` in the project (and that it, or something it's derived from, really has a `view` property).  The reference to `NSObject` in the error message is really suspicious.

Comment: Is there any chance that the `PopupViewController.swift` file is not marked as part of the target you're building?

Comment: It is `PopupViewController.swift` and it's marked for building. Anyway see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the File's Owners view property to the view in the interface builder.

[image]

Comment: Oh sure, you pass nil to the owner, which has no view property.

Comment: What should I pass? I just followed the answer of another question.

Comment: What is the File's owner' class in the .xib?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Anyway please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some messing in connections between StoryBoard XIB and swift classes (sorry I'm not with my iMac and I can't say you to send me a zip of the project)
I'll write here steps I usually follow to accomplish such things, hoping this can help:

- Create Xib file in your project. Place items on it as always. (ex: `MyViewController.xib`)
- Create a new Swift class (name usually is the same as the Xib) (ex: `MyViewController.swift`)
- In Interface Builder, select the xib, select the UIViewController and choose View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector.
- In the "Class" field select your custom swift class (`MyViewController.swift`)
- Connect IBOutlets and IBActions if you need to
- In `MyViewController.swift` add this extension:

  ```
  extension UIViewController {
  class func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
      return UINib(
          nibName: nibNamed,
          bundle: bundle
          ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIViewController
      }
  }
  ```
- In your MainController add this line wherever you need it (in button click or other places)

  ```
  var x = MyViewController.loadFromNibNamed("MyViewController") as MyViewController
  ```

X now is instance of your MyViewController and Xib files is already loaded.

Comment: "Create Xib file in StoryBoard" - What do you mean? I have Main.storyboard and Popup.xib - two different files.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm at work and typos are always hunting for me. I mean _Create a Xib file in your project_. I edit my answer..