# Switched to swift 2.0 and getting AnyObject error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nib, loadnibnamed

Why cam I getting the `Cannot convert value of type [AnyObject]! to expected argument type.` I am trying to load a nib into a view controller.

```
func loadNibNamed(name: String!, owner: AnyObject!, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> [View1]!{
    NSBundle.mainBundle(loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil)).lastObject
}
```

Comment: u can't use AnyObject use the class name from where its belong

Comment: what is class of `owner` and `options`

Comment: So View1 is the name of the nib if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right code in Swift2.0

NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil).last

lastObject is for Swift1.2 and now it isn't available in swift2.0 use last instead.

And to use it , you can convert it into UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func loadNibNamed(name: String, owner: AnyObject, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(name, owner: owner, options: options)
}
```

Comment: It's not placing the nib in the viewcontroller

Comment: @blee: I just correct your code. Here is your reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/31957214/3614616 if you want to custom view from xib file