# The crash of IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a custom view by xib in swift. The view shows correct and the `@IBAction` is also right. But when I add an `@IBOutlet`, the app will crash.

The error message is:

```
2016-03-15 22:32:16.650 ****[42692:1015001] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7f8ea483cd30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cancelBtn.'
```

And the xib:

[image: XIB Information]

And the code is:

```
 class PYChangeNameView: UIView { 
  var confirmAction: ((name: String?) -> ())? 
  var cancelAction: (() -> ())? 

  @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton! 

  private init() { 
   super.init(frame: CGRectZero) 
   if let view = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("PYChangeNameView") {    
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] 
    self.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds self.addSubview(view) 
   } 
  }

  @IBAction func cancelClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    PYCNVStaticValues.sharedInstance?.removeFromSuperview()
    PYCNVStaticValues.cancelAction?()
  }
}
```

The `@IBAction` works, but the `@IBOutlet` does not work.
    }

Comment: Is the button actually named "cancelBtn" in the xib? Based on the action name and the error message, I would guess it is named "cancel".

Comment: You can see the picture, the button is named "cancelBtn".

Comment: Have you added an IBOutlet to this button in any other place?

Comment: @HugoAlonso No, I had search the key "cancelBtn" in the project, only this place.

Comment: try and remove the IBOutlet from the inspector in this xib, rebuild, launch, if everything is OK, then set it back

Comment: @HugoAlonso I had tried this method, it not works for me.

Comment: So, if you remove the IBOutlet from the inspector it keeps giving you the error?

Comment: Isn't it funny that is says `NSObject...setValue:forUndefinedKey:` instead of for instance `UIViewController...setValue:forUndefinedKey:`. What does your files owner look like?

Comment: @HugoAlonso If i remove the `@IBOutlet`, it run right. But if I add `@IBOutlet`, it crashed.

Comment: @pbodsk ```class PYChangeNameView: UIView {

    var confirmAction: ((name: String?) -> ())?
    var cancelAction: (() -> ())?
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton!
    private init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        if let view = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("PYChangeNameView") {
            view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
            self.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            self.addSubview(view)
        }
    }

Comment: @pbodsk This is the content, It's a subclass of the `UIView`.

Comment: Try this approach and see if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24370563/2683201

Comment: @HugoAlonso Yes, this is my way.

Comment: @PlutoY has this worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the error: it's telling you that `NSObject` doesn't have a `cancelBtn` field. And why would it?

Looking at your screenshot, I can see that you have the `cancelBtn` outlet set on your `File's Owner`. (The outlet should be set to whatever is your custom view.)

Therefore I can conclude that your `File's Owner` object isn't getting properly associated with your `PYChangeNameView`, and the runtime thinks it's simply an `NSObject`. I believe you need to set that class as the type in your XIB - probably in the controls at right.

Check out this beautiful Retina-quality screenshot that I captured:

[image: Beautiful Screenshot at Retina Quality]

There may also be a need to set the *Module* field. You may get some insight from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24924966/1224741).

Comment: I think you're right, I was (slowly) getting to the same conclusion, just needed to be sure :-)

Comment: @QED How can i get propertly associated with the PYChangeNameView?

Comment: @PlutoY I added a beautiful Retina-quality screenshot to show you how.

Comment: @QED Is it the file owner right? If it is, I had set it.

Comment: @PlutoY it should be whatever is the custom view.

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure that your view's `xib` is a `PYChangeNameView`

[image: like This]

Comment: And that were it says **Module**, actually there's something different than **None**

Comment: ya your module should be your project name. not "none"

Comment: You also may just try deleting your outlet connection and control drag it back.

Comment: @DanielLeonard Yes, this is the way which I created the oulet. And the `module` is also my project name.